# Unable to load assests or render images from react App on Mac

Tags: reactjs, macos

My images in assets folder was not rendering, tried both relative and absolute path.It still wasn't rendering with little resource online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to fix it

1. Move the image or assets folder into Public Folder
2. Access the image using ./assests/logo.png or ./logo.png

**CSS**
background-image:url('./logo.png');

HTML
<img src='./assets/logo.png' alt:'image' />